# Is there something like pngcrush for GIFs?

Tags: optimization, gif

pngcrush does a very good job at reducing the size of PNG-Files. I was wondering if the was something similar for GIFs, which we still use in our applications (can't fix that quickly).

Google Page Speed claims that our GIF images could be optimized by a large amount, but doesn't recommend a way. I searched the web and couldn't find a tool or library.

Does anyone know a straight forward way to optimize those GIF-Files?

Comment: Btw - I'm also intimately familiar with GIF file format (wrote my bachelor's thesis on the topic and a .NET library for reading/writing them). I'm too sometimes frustrated by the lack of good low-level GIF editing/optimizing tools. I wonder what the demand for such software would be? Would you be willing to pay for that?

Comment: @Vilx: As the question implies (GIFs, which we _still_ use), GIF is considered a deprecated image format. That means most of its use is in legacy environments, i.e. environments that already have tooling. And from that you can deduce that there's likely little demand. Now, there might be demand for components to produce PNG's which are API compatible with existing components that produce GIFs - i.e. making it a "can fix that quickly" problem.

Comment: What do you mean - "API compatible"? And GIF is not really deprecated. There's still nothing else (short of heavyweight Flash) that can do animations on the web.

Comment: @Vilx: Not really. The solution seems to be to replace the GIFs by PNGs (we don't use animated GIFs) over time. I still don't get Page Speed's claim, though...

Comment: Just a guess - maybe it means that you should replace GIFs with PNGs? Static GIFs don't have much available for optimization. Well, they can include arbitrary text/data chunks; and it's possible to make a GIF with redundant palette entries... but I can't imagine any tool doing something THAT dumb. Hmm... unless... It's also possible to store a GIF file "uncompressed", which was occasionally done some time ago when the GIF patent issue was afloat.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I just ran across this problem and found [Gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) (as mentioned by Daidai). It's included in the Ubuntu repos (and probably other Linux distros) and the website has ports for Windows/Mac.

To optimize a set of images, you can use this command:

```
gifsicle --batch --optimize=3 *.gif
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 6):

gifsicle http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/

Answer (score -2):

If they are static GIFs, then converting them to PNGs and then running pngcrush on them will usually provide a good optimization. Also take care to inspect them with [TweakPNG](http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/) and remove any unnecessary parts.

For animated GIFs any decent editing software (although I can't name any) should already perform the few optimizations that are available. There isn't much to optimize anyway, unlike PNGs.

I know of an old piece of software called "Animagic GIF", but it's been abandoned for over 10 years at least... maybe you can still find it somewhere. I'm pretty sure that it saves optimized GIFs. It also has a further "optimize" feature, but I think that degrades picture quality (reduces colors), so just stick to regular save.

Comment: Although this is not really an answer to my question I accept it for showing me there's no good answer, surprisingly. Animagic GIF is too old and simple, so I will either use Photoshop to optimize the most important GIFs and eventually switch to PNG completely.

Comment: @Searle There is a better answer, see DisgruntledGoat's answer.

Answer (score -2):

Trout's GIF Optimizer is quite good.

[image: screenshot]

---

[Gif Reducer](http://www.gifreducer.com/) is online tool that reduces the number of colors in a gif.

Answer (score -2):

You could convert it to HTML5 video, just like http://gfycat.com does. They claim really small sizes (and it is mostly true, so besides being a very efficient solution it is also pretty a pretty cool one)